# Displaying Data with ReactJS - Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

I am trying to create a separate card dynamically for each element that I have *fetched* with React.

Being quite new to React, I am having this issue where I can't map each of my element so that I can use them in **the html**. The official error that I am getting is:

> Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Here is a [link to my json data](https://api.myjson.com/bins/r5pn2)

This is my React code:

```
export class ZonePreviewMenu extends React.Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        isLoading: true,
        rooms: []
    }
}

componentDidMount(){
    this.fetchData();
}

fetchData(){
    fetch("https://api.myjson.com/bins/r5pn2")
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data))
    .then(data => {this.setState({data: data })})
    .catch(error => console.log("parsing failed", error))
}

    render(){
        return(

                <div className="zone-panel">
                    <h2> Zones </h2>
                 { this.state.data.map((item, i) => {
                    console.log(item.name)
                 })

                 }

                    <div className="image-panel">
                        <div className="#">
                            <div className="icon-row-one">
                                <img src={thermoIcon}/> 21C
                                <button className="btn btn-default btn-circle btn-lg top-buttons"><img src={cameraIcon}/></button>
                                <button className="btn btn-default btn-circle btn-lg lights-button"><img src={lightsIcon}/></button>
                            </div>
                            <div className="icon-row-two">
                                <img src={peopleIcon}/> 60
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
        );
    }
}
```

This is the part where I get the error:

```
             { this.state.data.map((item, i) => {
                console.log(item.name)
             })

             }
```

Question: Why am I getting this error and how can I create a card for each element of the posted JSON object.

Comment: Your fetch call is asynchronous, so it doesn't complete before render tries to map over this.state.data. If you initialize data: [] inside your state, data will no longer be undefined and you won't see this error.

Comment: By writing `.then(data => console.log(data))` you make it so that `data` in `.then(data => {this.setState({data: data })})` is `undefined`, so you should remove that.

Comment: @Tholle even though that does solve the error, I still cannot console log any of the items. I can't display them either.

Comment: The `rooms` in the response is an object with array values where each object in those arrays have one property. You most likely want to turn that data into a flat array if you want to use `map` on it in the render method.

Comment: @Tholle changed the api data with [his here](https://api.myjson.com/bins/j3ptq) and it still gives the same result. Can't console log the elements or display the paragraph.

Comment: It's still a pretty odd data structure. It's an object where each key has an array with one object in it.

Comment: @Tholle can you suggest a better data structure then? Or how can I resolve this, thank you for the help so far.

Comment: It depends on your use case and if you're in control of the backend you get the data from, but an object `{ kitchen: { ... }, hotDesk: { ... }}` or an array of objects `[{ room: 'kitchen', ... }, { room: 'hotDesk', ... }]` would probably be easiest for you to work with.

Comment: @Tholle thanks, I'll look into this

Answer (score 1):

React will first render before the fetch call is finished using the initial state. In your initial state there's no data.

Define data as an empty array in your initial state

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        isLoading: true,
        rooms: [],
        data: []
   }
}
```